Indent/dedent in the Stacks Editor
I would love to have an indent and dedent keys in the new Stacks Editor.
This has already been requested for the old markdown editor, but the request seems to have been ignored, and it seems like the Stacks Editor is meant to have more robust features anyways.
In addition to all the old reasons, there seems to be Stacks Editor-specific use case for a dedent button. The Stacks Editor now makes code fences its default form of code formatting, which I'm all for! However, this makes it more difficult to replace code blocks with code fences. A dedent button would make this super easy to fix.

ctrl-k may be inline code, but ctrl-m is still there for code blocks (however it won't work if a language has been specified).

@Nickistired It dos code fences instead of code blocks, to the best of my knowledge.

Are we really trying to bring back “dedent”?

I just checked Google’s ngram viewer, and apparently we are, so, okay…

@beaker: Would you prefer "deindent"?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk “disindent”, please :D

"I can't fix these sorts of code samples in the Staging Ground" - yes you can. You don't want to. Let's keep it honest here, this is not about whether something is possible or not, it is about inconvenience and how far you are willing to go. There is nothing stopping you from painstakingly fixing indentation using the delete button, or to copy/paste it into a rich text editor, fix indentation using dedicated features such as code cleanup or column editing there, and then putting it back.

How often are people actually posting indented code when posting using the Stacks Editor?  I don't understand how this would happen, especially with this sample that appears to show an entire Python script.  Was the entire source file indented?

@RyanM If a new user posts indented code with the markdown editor in the Ask Wizard, their post goes to Staging Ground, where it’s hard to fix.

@Gimby I mean, sure. But is that really a good use of anyone’s time? I personally would much rather have a built-in feature than do any of those other things. In my eyes, making such a small change shouldn’t have to be “painstaking” or require me to open a whole other program.

@AndrewYim the point is that hyperbole and meta don't mix. Just keep it grounded. It's demotivating to have to do frequently which would be fair enough. Do you have to do these kind of edits frequently though? Again - let's keep it honest.

@AndrewYim I'm not sure how that answers my question about how often it occurs though.  The Ask Wizard uses the Stacks Editor, so any question coming through there used the Stacks Editor, in which it's at least harder to end up with overly indented code.

@RyanM Ok, now I'm just confused as to how this showed up in the first place. If the Ask Wizard uses the Stacks Editor, I have no idea how this user managed to get code blocks in their question. Edited the question accordingly.
