The Stacks Editor implementation of code formatting makes it much harder to edit questions in the Staging Ground
Just to be clear, I don't want a meta effect of votes on this question but it exemplifies the issue. I seemingly can't easily edit it back into shape like I used to be able to. The {} button has been replaced by a "code block" and I can't selectively remove text from that block.
If I try to remove the code block with highlighted portions of the text, it instead just collapses the code formatting for the whole question into plain text. The only way (it seems) for me to fix the question is to strip out the entire code formatting and then rebuild the correct indentation for the actual code. I'm struggling with this so it surely must be just as confusing to a new user to have created this in the first place.
Am I missing something? Something seems to have changed with the markdown.

Ok, so it's since been edited the way I wanted. What was I missing?

I just edited the Post without any problem, => by simply moving the \``markers to their correct place... (I also added thelang-py` Identifier for Syntax Highlighting.)

@chivracq I'm an idiot. I now see that there is a "markdown mode" option so I could have changed it there. Thank you

Oh yes, I indeed always use the "Full Markdown Mode" and type all Markdown myself. The only Icon I use from the Editor-bar is for placing Images.

It has definitely changed for the worse, though. I've edited plenty of questions in the past and I've never had to go into the actual markdown because {} could easily pull bits out of code formatting. I can't say I'm a fan of this new approach but at least it's functional

Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431217/4014959
